# Multivariable Chain Rule on a functional

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have $$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\Big(\frac{\partial L(t,y(t),y'(t),y''(t))}{\partial y''}\Big)$$ and I was wondering on how to calculate this in to an expanded differentiated form. I cant seem to get it right. The derivatives $y'(t)$ and $y''(t)$ are differentiated on $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing $L = L(t,a,b,c)$ you get
$$\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dt^2} L_c(t,a,b,c) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \left( L_{ct}(t,a,b,c) + a_t L_{ca}(t,a,b,c) + b_t L_{cb} (t,a,b,c) + c_t L_{cc}(t,a,b,c)\right) \\
= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(L_{y''t} + y'L_{y''y} + y''L_{y''y'} + y'''L_{y''y''}) \\
= L_{y''tt} + y'L_{y''ty} + y''L_{y''ty'} + y'''L_{y''ty''}\\
+ y'(L_{y''yt} + y' L_{y''yy} + y''L_{y''yy'} + y''' L_{y''yy''}) \\
+ y''(L_{y''y't} + y' L_{y''y'y} + y'' L_{y''y'y'} + y''' L_{y''y'y''}) \\
+ y'''(L_{y''y''t} + y' L_{y''y''y} + y'' L_{y''y''y'} + y''' L_{y''y''y''})$$
Where the indices indicate partial derivatives. You can now rearrance and use Schwartz' theorem to rearrange the partials into a favorable order if $L$ is a continuously differentiable functional.